Approximation with bounded function
Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the unit disc, and let $B(o,r) \subset B(o,r')$ be two balls contained in $\mathbb{D}$. Assume that we have a $C^{\infty}$ function $f: \mathbb{D} \to [a,b]$ which has all its derivatives bounded. Also, assume that $f$ has a minimum which is equal to $a$ (uniformly bounded on the disc and not only on compact subsets).
Now, I want to construct a function $g$ as follows:
$g\mid_{B(o,r)} = f $
$ g\mid_{B(o,r') \setminus B(o,r)} = A $
$ g\mid_{\mathbb{D} \setminus B(o,r')} = a $
where $A$ is an affine function that smoothly transitions between $f$ on $\partial B(o,r)$ and the constant function $a$.
Note that $g$ is almost everywhere smooth and its derivatives are all uniformly bounded on the disk. Additionally, the image of $g$ is in the interval $[a, b]$.
Next, I want to apply convolution to the function $g$ in a small neighborhood of $\partial B(o,r)$, to obtain a function $h$ which is smooth on $\mathbb{D}$.
We can have as much control as we want on the image of $h$ in the sense that for any $\epsilon$, we can find a neighborhood and a convolution such that $\operatorname{Im}(h) \subset [a-\epsilon, b+\epsilon]$.
What I want to ask is the following:

Can we apply the process above (that is, apply a convolution to smooth $g$) and have all the derivatives of $h$ (of any order) bounded, where the bounds depend on $f$ only?

